# css scrollLeft animate moves body vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am trying to write a function that horizontally scrolls a div to a specific point given a parameter. Everything functions properly except when the document/body is scrolled down and the function is executed by pressing a letter. When this happens the whole document/body is scrolled up to the top. I really can't figure out what I am doing wrong here but I don't want the page to scroll to the top.

an example of the code can be found at http://www.hokosounds.com/testRedesign/store-test.html#

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a').click(function(e, _letter){

        e.preventDefault();
        var _letter = $(this).html();
        scrollToLetter(_letter);

    });

    scrollToLetter = function(_letter) {
        var _distance = $('#'+_letter+'Start').position().left+$('#store-nav-artist-names').scrollLeft();
        $('#store-nav-artist-names').animate({
        scrollLeft: _distance
        }, 800);
    }; 

});
```

Comment: should this just be added anywhere in a js file?

Comment: if you make a jsfiddle of your project I will be happy to show you

Comment: No worries, you should be able to take off the onclick handlers on the A tags now

Answer (score 0):

The page will scroll to the top if you don't handle the click event to either `return false` or `event.preventDefault` http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

It will stop the behavior of a link being clicked.

Comment: ive tried putting : $("a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); }); 

and nothing changed? should the preventDefault be included in my function or is this a general statement?

Comment: Its normally included in your function but I see you have an onclick handler. Adding 'return false;' to your onclick will solve the issue. For example <a onclick="scrollToLetter('a');return false;" href="#">A</a>

Comment: Chris G-Jones solution is nicer, would recommend using that.